# Running Tomcat server Intellij Skip the test class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have successfully to deploy the tomcat server but the problem is when building artifacts. The process still include the test directory output even i have include skip test in maven pom and trying toggle skip test in maven pom. Also there is no test module in artifacts. In eclipse servers run normally although the test class have error. Thank you.

[image: Here my settings for tomcat]

Here is my artifacts:
[image]

Comment: is your war artifact listed as war:exploded under the Deployment tab of IntelliJ ?

Comment: Do you have tests in the directory configured as test source root? Otherwise the tests will be included in the compiler output and the compiler output will be included into your artifact. In case the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can verify your configuration.

Comment: Yes i have tests in the directory configured as test source root. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, to make the project exclude the test classes. Just add in the File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler --> Excludes --> Add the tests directory that you want to exclude